# Last used column only up to a specific last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have something that works but I don't want it to look passed column 25. I don't care about anything passed column 25. I would like a version that only looks in Column 1 through 25 instead of the whole sheet.

```
 LastCol = wb.Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Cells(curr_row, wb.Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: could you provide picture of your sheet?

Comment: It's just a regular blank sheet. nothing to see. I am loading values via a loop and filling in column by column .. I could have an internal counter but it's different on every row thats why it would be easier to check using the LastCol formula. There is always stuff to the right of col 25 which is why my formula above doesn't work.

Comment: no I am not sure it deserves it yet.  If @Jeeped could not get to an answer I doubt I will.  Try this: `lastCol = wb.Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Cells(curr_row, 1).end(xltoright).column`

Comment: also I tied that code never gets off the first col

Comment: It's a super standard formula to find lastcol with data. Whats not to understand??????? All I am asking is that I want it to look within column 1 through 25 instead of to the end of the excel sheet.

Comment: You have had three people try to understand what you want and fail.  So the problem lies in your explanation.

Comment: Ok, have you ever seen this LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ???  It's a VERY common way to look for the last column in a sheet with data. I would like a version that only looks in Column 1 through 25 instead of the whole sheet. There is literally no way to make this more clear.

Comment: okay that makes more sense.  Your original made it seem that you wanted the furthest right column or 25 which ever was less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited with better understanding of the question)

Your code should work fine, you just need to execute .End(xlToLeft) on the 26th column of the row, instead of the last.  Try:

```
LastCol = wb.Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Cells(curr_row, 26).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: great idea, but this won't work in my case. because there is always data passed col 25 on my sheet. I am looping through and adding stuff column by col